# What is gradient of the objective function of lasso regression

Tags: regression, optimization, lasso, gradient

In LASSO regression we minimise $(Xw-y)^T(Xw-y)+λ \|w \|$. How to find the gradient of its objective function?

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly, L1-norm is:
$$||w||_1=\sum_{i=1}^n |w_i|$$

Derivative of $y=|x|$ doesn't exist but its piecewise derivative exists except $x = 0$, and is $\text{sign}(x)$. So, above expression's *derivative* with respect to $w_k$ is $\text{sign}(w_k)$. After taking element-wise derivative and forming the gradient vector, we'll have the following:

$$\frac{\partial ||w||_1}{\partial w}=\text{sign}(w)$$

where $\text{sign}$ is element-wise sign operation.

Since the expression is a sum, the first part's derivative doesn't change wrt the norm used, and is the same as before.